# Solving Sine Equation

Tags: trigonometry, real-numbers, transcendental-equations

I'm trying to find all the real solutions of the following trigonometric equation :

$$ \frac{\sin 3x}{\sin 2x} = A $$

I can see that $x$ is some integer function of $\pi$ , but I cannot find the exact expression for it using normal trigonometric identities due to $A$ being present.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please give some context what your background is in mathematics,  what you have tried to do to solve this problem, what went wrong, etc. Without this information it is difficult to help, since we don't know where you're holding.

Comment: $\frac  1 {\sqrt {1+A^{2}}}\sin (3x)-\frac  A {\sqrt {1+A^{2}}} \sin (2x)=0$. Does this give some ideas?

Comment: Use identities to rewrite the left side as $a \cos x + b \sec x$, i.e. you get a quadratic equation in $\cos x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! You have to show your work , to avoid closure of questions without effort , here are two suggestions (1) You mention some normal trigonometric identities you know of : You can include that in the Post (2) You say general unknown $A$ makes it harder : You could try to solve when $A=0$ & when $A=1$ to include in your Post. That inclusion will prevent closure of questions without effort !

Comment: WizardLizard, you should accept the answer by user DODO. You probably won't find anything better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With [Double Angle Identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/double-angle-identities/) & [Triple Angle Identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/triple-angle-identities/) , we have :

$$\frac{\sin 3x}{\sin 2x}=\frac{-4\sin^3x+3\sin x}{2\sin x\cos x}=\frac{-4\sin^2 x+3}{2\cos x}=A$$

So , we get the Equation :
$$4\cos^2 x-2A\cos x-1=0$$

It is Quadratic in $\cos x$.

Then , the Quadratic Solutions are :

$$\cos x=\frac{A\pm \sqrt{A^2+4}}{4}$$

Note that we should carefully choose the '$\pm$' from $A$ , since $|\cos x| \le 1$

We then get $x$ with the trigonometric inverse of the valid Quadratic Solutions , which will have the Principal Value :
$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{A\pm \sqrt{A^2+4}}{4}\right)$$

Solutions :
$$x = 2 \pi n \pm \theta$$

Maybe my calculation is correct.
[[ User Sahaj & User Acccumulation have made corrections to the calculations via comments ]]

Comment: Very good solution. Isn´t it $\cos (x)=\frac{A}{4}\pm \sqrt{(\frac{A}{4})^2+\frac{1}{4}}$?

Comment: Actually the calculation is slightly incorrect. $\cos x = \frac{A \pm \sqrt{A^2 + \color{red}{4}}}{4}$.

Comment: Arccos is not the inverse of cos. Given y = cos(x), arccos gets only one value of x, even though there are an infinite number of such.

Comment: It may be correct , @Sahaj , you could recheck. Consider this : Even the $A^2$ should be $4A^2$ , then $2$ comes out of the $\sqrt{}$ & gets cancelled with a term in the Denominator. Looks right !

Comment: Valid Point , I have addressed that , @Acccumulation , all Solutions are listed there !

Comment: @Prem, see this on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4x%5E2-2Ax-1%3D0). The expression given in this highly voted answer is **incorrect** and should be corrected. Solving for $x$ in $4x^2-2ax-1=0$ gives via the quadratic formula $$x = \frac{2a \pm \sqrt{4a^2-4(4)(-1)}}{8} = \frac{2a \pm 2\sqrt{a^2+4}}{8} =\frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4}}{4}$$

Comment: Nice one , I got it now , @Sahaj , I did not verify OP calculation & that was why I said "It **may** be correct" & "**Looks** right" , though now I can say "You are correct" : I will edit the Post !